# UICollectionView scroll to specific section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Using Objective C and Xcode I have created a `UICollectionView` with 10 sections and all works fine.  Is there anyway to set the section to which is viewed when first shown?  By default it shows sections 0-9, but I want it to start at section 5.

Answer (score 28):

You can call `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` in your `viewDidAppear:` method.

You can hold a reference to the cell you want to scroll to, then use `indexPathForCell:` to get the index path.

The following are the scroll positions you can choose from

```
UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone
UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop
UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom
UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight
```

Comment: What if that particular section has no items, just a header view?

Comment: I find this doesn't work if paging is enabled. The scrollToItemAtIndexPath always positions the cell at the requested position, whereas what you want is to centre the page (as it would if you manually scrolled). If you don't have a cell that is in the centre of a page, this doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

In case you know where you want to scroll to in terms of an integer row and section, you can use those integers in the

```
NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:inSection:
```

method to create an NSIndexPath instead of keeping a reference to a cell and then calling indexPathForCell:.  Also, you can move this code to the viewWillAppear: method if you want the scrolling to happen before the view is displayed.